# TextLayout with linebreak and tab

Tags: java, swing, text, line-breaks, tabular

I have got a `JComponent` which draws a multiline attributed string with `Textlayout` which runs very well:

```java
public static float drawMultiAttributedString(Graphics2D g2d, AttributedString str, String plainString, int maxWidth, int startX, float startY){

    FontRenderContext fontRenderCtx = g2d.getFontRenderContext();

    AttributedCharacterIterator attrCharIter = str.getIterator();
    LineBreakMeasurer lineBreakMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(attrCharIter, fontRenderCtx);
    float x = startX;
    float y = startY;

    int next; 
    int limit; //länge bis zum nächsten umbruch
    int charat; 
    String tested = plainString;

    while (lineBreakMeasurer.getPosition() < attrCharIter.getEndIndex()) { 

          next = lineBreakMeasurer.nextOffset(maxWidth);
          limit = next;
          charat = tested.indexOf("\n", lineBreakMeasurer.getPosition()+1);
          if(next > (charat - lineBreakMeasurer.getPosition()) && charat != -1){
             limit = charat - lineBreakMeasurer.getPosition();
          }
          TextLayout layout = lineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(maxWidth, lineBreakMeasurer.getPosition() + limit, false);

              y += layout.getAscent(); //höhe des haupttextes

          layout.draw(g2d, x, y);

          y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading(); 
    }

    return y - startY;
}
```

The problem is, that `Textlayout` doen't render tabulators, which I need. 
Does anyone have an idea how I could include also tabulators? Any ideas?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

A [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with one or more custom renderers may be an easier alternative. `DefaultTableCellRenderer` extends `JLabel`, which admits [HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) and locale-specific [formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).